# SQL server query for two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I need help to make query :)

I have two tables, TableA and TableB. In TableB have many records related to TableA

TableA:

```
Id  Label
 1   abc
 2   def
 3   gef
```

TableB:

```
Id tableA_id  due_at
 1    1        2016-05-25
 2    1        2015-05-25
 3    1        2014-05-25
```

I want to make the query where I am able to check every record of TableB. Below is my current query but it checks only last record instead of all

```
SELECT a.id, b.due_at
FROM tableA a
  LEFT JOIN tableB b ON b.tableA_id = a.id
where (b.due_at > '2016-05-26' OR b.due_at is null)
```

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: because you have the condition `b.due_at > '2016-05-26'` so only one row from TableB will be considered

Comment: Apart from the dates issue. Why are you joining tables if you don't do anything with table A (only selecting the ID which you actually have in B)? You could directly select the tableA_id from table B

Comment: Mine expected result is row 1 from TableB will not appear in result. Currently I am getting all the three rows

Answer (score 0):

check where condition `b.due_at > '2016-05-26'` As per info you don't have records in `**TableB**` who has its `due_at greater than '2016-05-26'`

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to select the column a.id which already exists in the table B, Thus Join is not needed in your case.

Also, the Result of your query should be zero as you don't have data in table b having b.due_at > '2016-05-26', they are all < '2016-05-26'.